# Android OpenCV CameraWrapper library missing

Tags: android, opencv

I use OpenCV for Android and get

```
D/OpenCV::camera(17555): CameraWrapperConnector::connectToLib ERROR: cannot dlopen camera wrapper library /data/app-lib/org.opencv.engine-2/libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so, dlerror="dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android11BufferQueueC1EbRKNS_2spINS_19IGraphicBufferAllocEEE" referenced by "libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so"..."
```

I know `libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so` is missing an I have to copy it manually to my device. But how can I do that?

Comment: Have you followed the Async Initalization instructions described in the OpenCV docs?

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-async-initialization

Comment: Yes. I know the initalization is correct because it works fine on one of my devices. But on my new one it does not run and I get this log.

Comment: Maybe OpenCV has problems with that device camera. Try using OpenCV Java camera instead of OpenCV Native camera.